# I want spacing between image inside a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: These are the images]

I want some css to design just like this picture i want these three share images inside a div all three images. And these should have proper gap like the image above.

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <div  class="page-small-title">
   Jude Alix Patrick Salomon, le DG de l'IGF devient Ministre des Finances
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="">
  <img src="images/read_news/u864.png"/>
  <img src="images/index/share_icon_facebook_u59.png"/>
  <img src="images/index/share_icon_tweeter_u60.png"/>
</div>
```

**This is the example code. The image below is the exact requirement to achieve.**

[image: The code should look like this example image]

Comment: Here what is the use of php ?

Comment: add padding to image,  img { padding:5px;}

Comment: Sorry php was tagged by mistake . i was working in php to manipulate data . in same project

Comment: i want a css which i can use in div to make this appearance not in each image. @nirali

Comment: @devpokhriya then give padding to div

Answer (score 0):

Use padding to add space in between things.

```html
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="page-small-title">Jude Alix Patrick Salomon, le DG de l'IGF devient Ministre des Finances</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-left: 100px;">
    <img src="images/read_news/u864.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_facebook_u59.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_tweeter_u60.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: i already came to this solution i want something that i can use in outside div not in each image tag

Comment: I edited it. So you want space in between the left and your div?

Answer (score 0):

add css below

```
.col-lg-2 {
text-align: right;
}
or
.col-lg-2 {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
.col-lg-2 img {
margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code define `col-md` `col-sm` `col`

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
    <div  class="page-small-title">Jude Alix Patrick Salomon, le DG de l'IGF devient Ministre des Finances
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-right">
    <img src="images/read_news/u864.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_facebook_u59.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_tweeter_u60.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-xs-4 img {
 margin-left: 8px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
    <div  class="page-small-title">Jude Alix Patrick Salomon, le DG de l'IGF devient Ministre des Finances
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 text-right">
    <img src="images/read_news/u864.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_facebook_u59.png"/>
    <img src="images/index/share_icon_tweeter_u60.png"/>
</div>
```

I think this is the solution i was looking